# Angular UI Bootstrap modal is duplicating event listeners, not sure why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to listen for events inside an angular-ui bootstrap modal controller, and I haven't been able to grasp why new instances of my modal are duplicating event listeners.

In the following code and [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2fd1J4nBPVvFgemmLVZK?p=preview), repeated triggering of the test function runs duplicate versions of the event handler.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ]);
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
  $scope.$on("test", function(event, x) {
    console.log("Test! " + x);
  });
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $modal,$timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.test = function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      backdrop: 'static',
      templateUrl: 'modal.tpl.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
    });

    var sequence = $timeout(function(){});
    [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(x) {
      sequence = sequence.then(function() {
        return $timeout(function() {
          $rootScope.$broadcast("test", x);
        }, 1000);
      });
    });
    sequence.then(function() {
      modalInstance.dismiss('complete');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known (and fixed) bug in the ui-bootstrap version 0.10.0, the modal scope is not destroyed after the modal window is closed: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1643

Comment: At first I just added that small change to my ui-bootstrap.js to no avail. Then I built my own snapshot off the master branch and that seems to have the scope destroying properly.